# How to force svn.exe to ignore files from specific changeset when committing?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, version-control

I have a custom tool that uses `svn.exe` for committing files, and my project has several files to ignore on every commit (configuration files). This scenario is working well with TortoiseSVN, which moves them into a changeset with "ignore-on-commit" name. `svn.exe` has parameters to commit changes only from the particular changeset, but it doesn't has one to commit all files except ones in particular changeset. Any ideas how to do this? 
Thanks!

P.S. This is already implemented in TortoiseSVN I just didn't know how :(

Comment: If you never want to commit the files, then why not add then to `svn:ignore` and exclude them from version control completely?

Comment: I have two problems here: 
1. I need a copy of config file in repository, this can be done with putting "app.config.setup" and then just renaming it when needed, but I don't want to remove it from svn cos any team member will need to resolve conflict or will loose its config if it is the same as in repository

2. I don't want to write additional command on build server to rename app.config.setup to app.config before build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say this is a Tortiose feature and not part of the underlying svn libraries.

I think the best way to do this if you are using the svn command line is to specify the files you do want to commit. I assume you are using svn from some type of script so it should be doable. You can list the files you want to commit or generate a text file with a list of files and use the --targets command to specify the list of files.

You could if you wanted create a list of all the files except the ones in question and create an alias that will commit --targets mycommitlist.txt or something.

Comment: Thank you for your time, yes this is a solution I was thinking about, but actually I can't figure out quickly how to commit multiple files, what does --targets command?

Comment: -- targets FILENAME
--targets FILENAME
Tells Subversion to get the list of files that you wish to operate on from the filename that you provide instead of listing all the files on the command line.

You can also just list the files you want to commit:

svn ci filea.cs fileb.cs filec.cs

But if you have hundreds of files you should use the targets param passing the name of a textfile you create on the fly with your build script.